# Sitecore 8 MVC add Class to Image rendered as HtmlString

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.2

I have a very simple component, it just does consist of a single image.

The Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
      ActionResult ret = null;
      if (RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item != null)
      {
        IntroImageModel model = 
        CreateModel(RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item);
        ret = View(model);
      }
      return ret;
    }

    private IntroImageModel CreateModel(Item item)
    {

      IntroImageModel introImage = new IntroImageModel();
      introImage.IntroImage = new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(item, 
      FieldNames.INTROIMAGE_INTROIMAGE));
      return introImage;
    }
```

The Model:

```
 public class IntroImageModel
  {
    public IntroImageModel()
    {

    }

    public HtmlString IntroImage { get; set; }
  }
```

The View:

```
@model ON.LSX.FEATURE.CONTENT.Models.IntroImageModel
@{
  Layout = null;
}


@Model.IntroImage
```

I need to add a specific class to the  tag that is produced by this code, but I have absolutely no idea how to do it, anyone can help?

Answer (score 2):

try this on the View, as you can see, you can add the class as a parameter

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("IntroImage", new { mw = 1000, mh = 560, @class = "img-responsive" })
```

There are also some additional parameters that you can change